# Return specific object in callback method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table/model that has a parent-child relationship. 
The idea is to allow "aliases" for artist names.

Table: artists

```
+----+--------------------+-----------+
| id | name               | parent_id |
+----+--------------------+-----------+
|  1 | The Rolling Stones |           |
|  2 | Rolling Stones     |         1 |
+----+--------------------+-----------+
```

File: artist.rb

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :songs
  has_many   :children, class_name: 'Artist', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
  belongs_to :parent,   class_name: 'Artist'
end
```

I'm trying to get the parent artist through an alias name, so I tried to achieve this in the `after_find` callback. 
I added this to the `Artist` class:

```
  after_find :get_parent_if_exists

  private
  def get_parent_if_exists
    Artist.find( self.parent_id ) if self.parent_id
  end
```

Now, when doing `Artist.find_by( name: "Rolling Stones" )`, I hoped it would return object with ID 1, but it returns ID 2. However, I see that the parent object is queried but not returned.
My question: Is there a way to return that object in the `after_find` callback?

I expect it is not possible, but I wanted to ask it.

Comment: why not use a scope to get the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing stuff up a little bit.

`after_find` callback is there to help you perform something after the object is found.

What `Artist.find_by( name: "Rolling Stones" )` is returning is an object that meets the filter - you *can not not return another object* then the one, that is found in the database.

Of course, you can override the [`find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) method, but that is senseless.

---

## EDIT

To get the parent, you already have an existing method, provided by Rails when you state `belongs_to :parent`.

So

```
Artist.find_by( name: "Rolling Stones" ).parent
```

would have to return artist with the `The Rolling Stones` name.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and confirming my assumption. I was wondering if it was possible "somehow".

Comment: @lxxxvi if this answers your question please consider accepting it.